How to use Redemption Loader in Access 2016
I am currently building a database using Access 2016 and started using Redemption Loader to bypass the outlook security and enable me to send automatic emails from Access without user intervention.
I have purchased the distributable version of Redemption and registered the dll on my development machine and added the Redemption Loader module in the VBA editor. This works perfectly until another user logs into the database to test it as the redemption COM library reference is missing.
It was my understanding that Redemption Loader would load Redemption dynamically at run time but for anyone but me, it doesn't work. I am a little inexperienced so think I'm definitely missing something but have been unable to find anything online to help.
I have code which sits behind the 'on click' event of a button on one of my forms but I'm wondering whether I need to load Redemption on start up of the database to enable others to use the database without errors. If so, how would I do this and what code would I need?
Here is a copy of the code I have referenced which is in my form:
Private Sub SaveFirstAuth_Click()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNamespace As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim SafeItem As Object
Dim oItem As Object
Dim Redemption As Object
Set Redemption = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Dim OrgURN As String
Dim GrantURN As String
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

OrgURN = "Org URN " & Me.OrganisationURN
GrantURN = "Grant URN " & Me.GrantURN

If IsNull(Me.FirstAuthorisation) Then
    If IsNull(Me.FirstAuthorisationDate) Then
        If IsNull(Me.FinalAuthorisation) Then
    MsgBox "Please add first authorisation, date and final authorisation"
        End If
    
    End If
    
Else

'Email message text
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "Organisation Name: " & OrganisationName & ",<p>" _
    & GrantURN & ",<p>" & "Payment ready for final authorisation."

'Create outlook session
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    olNamespace.Logon 'logon to outlook
    
'Create a new mail item
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0) 'O = olMailItem
    Set SafeItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
    SafeItem.Item = olMail
        
'Set sender address, text format, recipient, subject and send
    SafeItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "crtsupport@coalfields-regen.org.uk"
    SafeItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    SafeItem.HTMLBody = msg
    SafeItem.To = Me.FinalAuthorisation.Column(1)
    SafeItem.Subject = "Payment for Authorisation"
    SafeItem.Send
    SafeItem.SaveAs "\\IT\CRTSupportDatabase\Documents\" & OrgURN & "\" & GrantURN & "\" & "Payment Authorised.msg"

'Disable authorisation fields and update payment status
    FirstAuthorisation.Enabled = False
    FirstAuthorisationDate.Enabled = False
    FinalAuthorisation.Enabled = False
    
    Me.PaymentStatus = "Awaiting final authorisation"
    Me.SaveFirstAuth.Enabled = False

    MsgBox "Payment authorised"
    Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.Close

    Set SafeItem = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
End If
    
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg As String
    msg = Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    MsgBox msg

End Sub


Any help would be really appreciated.

Do you mean you cannot create an instance of a Redemption object if the code is running under the identity of a local user other than he one who installed the dll? Make sure Redemption is installed in HKLM rather than HKCU - run elevated command prompt and user regsvr32.exe top install Redemption for all local users, not just the current one.

That's great, thanks! That's helped me solve the issue and get Redemption working.
